# Expectation Maximum 

Tags: pr.probability

Hi,
In my research, I have the following problem. Let $X,Y$ two i.i.d random variables and a function $u(x)=x^2$ if $x>0$ 
and $ u(x)= -\beta\ (-x)^2$  if $x\leq{}0$ with $\beta\geq{}1$

I need to find the conditions such that there is

$\alpha\in{}(0,1)$

that maximizes

$Eu(\alpha X+(1-\alpha) Y)$.

Thanks

Comment: The convoluted way you have written the definition for $u(x)$ when $x\le0$ makes me suspect a typing mistake. Also, what do you mean by “the conditions”? I suspect it can be tricky to find necessary and sufficient conditions, so a stronger hint of what exactly you need could be helpful.

Comment: By conditions, do you mean conditions on the distribution of X (and therefore Y)?

Comment: Yes, I think there must be some conditions on the cumulative distribution of X and Y.

Comment: One way to study this problem is to think under what conditions of the distributions of X and Y, $\alpha=0$ or $\alpha=1$ can not be an optimum.

Comment: What happen with the maximum if the function is changed to:

$ u(x)=(x)^{0.5}$ if $x>0$

$ u(x)= -\beta\ (-x)^{0.5}$  if $x\leq{}0$ with $\beta\geq{}1$.


Answer (score 1):

This is just a comment, not an answer. (I don't have enough reputation to write comments.)

Some basic statements that you probably knew already:

If $P(X \leq 0) = 1$, then there will always be such $\alpha$. Likewise if $P(X \geq 0) = 1$, there will never be such $\alpha$. This is from concavity/convexity of $u(x)$.

If the law of X is symmetric about zero, there will always be such $\alpha$. In particular $\alpha = 1/2$ will be better than $\alpha = 0$ or 1.

I agree with Harald that a general answer may be too much to hope for. Are you more interested in sufficient conditions or necessary conditions? Is there a particular family of distributions that you care about? Do you expect $\beta$ to be very close to 1, or much larger?

If you're looking for a sufficient condition, maybe you could let

$f(\alpha) = E[u(\alpha X + (1-\alpha) Y)]$

and look for situations in which $f'(0) > 0$.